# Finding a better upper bound for an integral of a product of $n$ terms

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals, estimation

So I'm trying to find and upper bound for the integral

$$
\int\limits_{a}^b \! (x-x_1)^2 \cdots (x-x_n)^2\, \mathrm{d}x,
$$

where $x_i \in [a,b], \enspace \forall i=1,\dots ,n.$ I've tried evaluating a single facotr $(x-x_i)^2$ but all I've gotten was the obvious one:

$$
(x-x_i)^2 \leq (b-a)^2, \enspace \forall i=1,\dots,n,
$$

which as a result gives me:

$$
\int\limits_{a}^b \! (x-x_1)^2 \cdots (x-x_n)^2\, \mathrm{d}x \leq (b-a)^{2n+1}.
$$

That bound is not that good for what I need. Any suggestions on how to make it better?

Comment: For one factor the max seems to occur when $x_1$ is at the midpoint of $[a,b]$ where the integral is $(b-a)^3/12.$ This beats your result $(b-a)^3$ by a factor of $1/12$ -- I don't know whether it generalizes easily for more factors.

Comment: @coffemath For one factor you can take $a$ instead of the midpoint $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and you get $\frac{(b-a)^3}{3}$, so I don't think your upper bound is correct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, however, the $x_i$ aren't arbitrary, they are fixed points chosen as zeros of a certain class of polynomials (nodes for numeric integration), so the case that one of them is at the midpoint doesn't have to be true. @coffeemath

Comment: I also take back my commented claim, in that the actual max occus when $x_1$ is at an endpoint of $[a,b]$ and is as said by Martin, But as now OP made clear the $x_i$ are fixed, more must be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Hölder:
$$
I=\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_1)^2\ldots(x-x_n)^2 dx \leq \left(\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_1)^4 dx \right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_2)^4 \ldots (x-x_n)^4dx \right)^{1/2} \leq \\
\leq \left(\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_1)^4 dx \right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_2)^8 dx \right)^{1/4}\left(\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_3)^{8}\ldots(x-x_n)^8 dx\right)^{1/4} \leq \ldots \\
\leq \left(\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_1)^4 dx \right)^{1/2}\left(\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_2)^{8} \right)^{1/4} \left(\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_3)^{16}dx \right)^{1/8}\ldots \left(\int_{a}^{b} (x-x_n)^{2^{n+1}} dx\right)^{1/2^n} = \\
=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_i)^{2^{i+1}}dx \right)^{2^{-i}}
$$

We have to evaluate $\int_{a}^{b}(x-x_i)^{2^{i+1}}dx$. Making the substitution $x-x_i = y$, we have:
$$
\left(\int_{a-x_i}^{b-x_i}y^{2^{i+1}}dy \right)^{1/2^{i}}=\left(\frac{(b-x_i)^{2^{i+1}+1}-(a-x_i)^{2^{i+1}+1}}{2^{i+1}+1} \right)^{1/2^{i}} 
$$

Then, if $0\leq a \leq b$, 
$$
I\leq \left(\frac{(b-x_1)^{5}-(a-x_1)^{5}}{5} \right)^{1/2} \ldots \left(\frac{(b-x_n)^{2^{n+1}+1}-(a-x_n)^{2^{n+1}+1}}{2^{n+1}+1} \right)^{1/2^n} \leq \\
\leq \left(\frac{b^5 - a^5}{5} \right)^{1/2}\ldots \left(\frac{b^{2^{n+1}+1}-a^{2^{n+1}+1}}{2^{n+1}+1} \right)^{1/2^{n}}
$$

Let's check if this is actually decent. Assume $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and take $x_1 = 1/3$ and $x_2 = 2/3$. The integral is:
$$
I=\int_{0}^{1}\left(x-\frac{1}{3}\right)^2 \left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)^2 dx = \frac{7}{810} \approx 0.008642
$$

The bound you got was $1$ ($(b-a)^{2n+1}=1^3 = 1$). Our gives:
$$
I\leq \left(\frac{1}{5} \right)^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{9} \right)^{1/4} \approx 0.26
$$

So, not that great, and maybe it got a little bit too complicated, but I think this is fun! Maybe this sparks some other ideas.

Comment: That's not a bad upper bound, I believe. If you take $x_1=0$ and $x_2=0$, the integral turns out to be $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: @MartínForsbergConde Maybe it works better when the points are somewhat close (?). I'm not sure. I'm fairly certain one can do much better with less complications.

Comment: I love how you used Hölder, however, I have a question. In the part "Then we have...", by what argument do you get that i.e. in the first factor $(b-x_1)^5 - (a-x_1)^5 \leq b^5 - a^5$*. If $x_1 < 0$, I don't see how that is true. (I tried with $a=-1, b=2, x_1 = -0.5$) @ViníciusNovelli

Comment: @Toni1234 you're right, I wasn't careful enough. I edited, adding that it holds only if $0\leq a \leq b$. Maybe there's a way to adapt it to the general case. I'll come back if I come up with something. Thanks for letting me know!